# Javascript Output cause Unexpected token <

Tags: javascript

I am outputting a bunch of content from PHP to JavaScript. They look correct in the source http://example.themobu.com/mychinaroots/ from line 188 in the source to line 293 (the add and addIntroduce functions). However, I'm getting Unexpected token < on jquery.js:2 so none of the text are able to be outputted. Here is a sample snippet

```
callback  : function() {
  tempArr = [Number("60"), Number("-108.632812")];
  paths_array[2].temp.push({
    'order'   : 50,
    'location': tempArr
  });
  add(jQuery(this), number += 1, "Cycle", "http://example.themobu.com/mychinaroots/?p=99", "Lorem ipsum Esse et magna ex culpa non qui nisi mollit cillum dolore amet consectetur elit Duis sed fugiat anim occaecat ea minim velit occaecat sed anim pariatur commodo Ut do ea esse dolore Excepteur dolor proident aliqua et irure deserunt magna Duis dolore id nisi sunt sunt esse aliquip consequat cillum pariatur sint magna ...", 60, -108.632812, '', 'http://example.themobu.com/mychinaroots/wp-content/themes/mychinaroots/images/6-default.png');

  tempArr = [Number("-48"), Number("24")];
  paths_array[0].temp.push({
    'order'   : 35,
    'location': tempArr
  });
  paths_array[2].temp.push({
    'order'   : 35,
    'location': tempArr
  });
  add(jQuery(this), number += 1, "Kema", "http://example.themobu.com/mychinaroots/?p=95", "Lorem ipsum Esse et magna ex culpa non qui nisi mollit cillum dolore amet consectetur elit Duis sed fugiat anim occaecat ea minim velit occaecat sed anim pariatur commodo Ut do ea esse dolore Excepteur dolor proident aliqua et irure deserunt magna Duis dolore id nisi sunt sunt esse aliquip consequat cillum pariatur sint magna ...", -48, 24, '', 'http://example.themobu.com/mychinaroots/wp-content/themes/mychinaroots/images/7-default.png');

  tempArr = [Number("-40"), Number("36")];  
  paths_array[2].temp.push({
    'order'   : 25,
    'location': tempArr
  });
  add(jQuery(this), number += 1, "Rad", "http://example.themobu.com/mychinaroots/?p=91", "Lorem ipsum Esse et magna ex culpa non qui nisi mollit cillum dolore amet consectetur elit Duis sed fugiat anim occaecat ea minim velit occaecat sed anim pariatur commodo Ut do ea esse dolore Excepteur dolor proident aliqua et irure deserunt magna Duis dolore id nisi sunt sunt esse aliquip consequat cillum pariatur sint magna ...", -40, 36, '', 'http://example.themobu.com/mychinaroots/wp-content/themes/mychinaroots/images/4-default.png');

  if( jQuery("#main").hasClass("index") ) {
    addIntroduce(jQuery(this), "Welcome to My Blog", "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p><br><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p><br><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p><br><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>", 42, 95 );
  }
} //End Callback
```

Comment: 1. this piece of code looks syntactically correct (though it's terrible). 2. Use chrome and its chrome dev tools to pinpoint the exact place of the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the call to `addIntroduce`.

```
function addIntroduce(jQuerythis, title, content, lati, longi) {
    //var string = JSON.stringify(content);
    console.log(jQuery.parseJSON(content));
}
```

You are expecting the `content` to be an json string (because you are parsing it to a json object) but you are passing a html string to it in the call `addIntroduce(jQuery(this), "Welcome to My Blog", "<p>.....</p>", 42, 95 );`

It is the line `jQuery.parseJSON(content)` which is throwing the error.

Comment: To add one more point, you can also escape some special characters if you require using `escape(content);` before parsing it!

Comment: lol, cuz I was previously using json_encode in PHP...forgot to remove it